# Create custom object with Mongify

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-migration, embedding

I am trying to migrate my sql db to mongoDB.
I have generated the basic translation file using mongify.
Now I need to create custom Object and manipulate the records as per need.

E.g.

```
table "acklog" do
    column "name", :string
    column "updated_at", :string
    column "id", :key, :as => :integer
end

table "testlog", :embed_in => :acklog, :as => :object do
    column "id", :key, :as => :integer
    column "first", :string
    column "middle", :string
    column "last", :string
    column "acklog_id", :integer, :references => "acklogs"

    before_save do |test_row, ack_row, unset_ack_row|                     
    ack_row.name = test_row.delete('first')       

  end
end
```

I am tring to move the columns "first","middle" and "last" from "testlog" table to "acklog table" under the "name" column as object.

It should behave something like:

```
name:{
   firstname: value from "first" column of "testlog" table
   middlename: value from "middle" column of "testlog" table
   lastname: value from "lastname" column of "testlog" table
}
```

Currently I am able to replace "name" with "first" column value, but i need to create object as "name".

Please help me with this.

Comment: I have the issue.Please help with above issue

Comment: Any updates on this issue ??

Comment: @PiyushChoudhary Sorry for late reply, but I was not able to fix this issue and I created my own custom script as per my need.

Comment: Guys, any update on this question?